# Overlapping instances error with single instance in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have the following code on Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, ExistentialQuantification, ConstraintKinds #-}

import Data.Proxy

class C p a b where
    c :: p b -> a -> Maybe (Ctx b)

class X a

instance X ()

data Ctx ctx = forall a. ctx a => Ctx a

instance C p (Ctx a) a where
    c _ = Just

instance C Proxy a b where
    c _ _ = Nothing

x :: Maybe (Ctx X)
x = c (Proxy :: Proxy X) (Ctx () :: Ctx X)
```

But when I tried to compile this code (or load in ghci) I got the error:

```
    * Overlapping instances for C Proxy (Ctx X) X
        arising from a use of `c'
      Matching instances:
        instance C p (Ctx a) a
          -- Defined at Main.hs:14:10
      There exists a (perhaps superclass) match:
      (The choice depends on the instantiation of `'
       To pick the first instance above, use IncoherentInstances
       when compiling the other instance declarations)
    * In the expression: c (Proxy :: Proxy X) (Ctx () :: Ctx X)
      In an equation for `x': x = c (Proxy :: Proxy X) (Ctx () :: Ctx X)
   |
21 | x = c (Proxy :: Proxy X) (Ctx () :: Ctx X)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why?

If I remove the last instance declaration `instance C Proxy a b`, it works fine. Why?

I try add `{-# OVERLAPPING #-}` pragma on first instance declaration or `{-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}` on second but error is still there. Why?

But if I will mark second instance as `{-# INCOHERENT #-}` it will be compiled successfuly.

Comment: If you want more control, you should use a closed type family instead of overlapping instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instances `C p' (Ctx a') a'` and `C Proxy a' b'` are *equally specific* matches for the constraint `C Proxy (Ctx a'') b''`, essentially because they both require a single substitution in the class head `C p a b`, namely `p ~ Proxy` or `a ~ Ctx a'`.

Overlapping instances only work when the compiler can select a *most specific* matching instance, which is why this code requires `IncoherentInstances` in order to select the first match. Without further context on what you’re trying to do, it’s hard to advise on how you can change your code to avoid this. You don’t *need* to avoid it if you can ensure that both instances produce the same behaviour, but they don’t currently. What do you expect the value of `x` to be?

As @AntC points out in the comments, one way to prioritise one instance over the other is to move the matching *out* of the instance head, thereby making it less specific, and introduce equality constraints instead:

- `instance (p ~ Proxy) => C p a b`
- `instance (a ~ Ctx a', b ~ a') => C p a b`

Such constraints are introduced *after* matching an instance. Then you can use pragmas to specify that, for example, the less-specific instance is `OVERLAPPABLE`, and/or more-specific instances are `OVERLAPPING`.

If you intend this relation you’re representing to be a *function*, then it may be easier to reason about an implementation based on a (closed) type family instead of the full generality of a MPTC.

Comment: Thanks! But why ghc doesn't show second instance in matching instances list?

I'm trying to implement the conception of 'castable' classes (sush as Semigroup a => Monoid a) and, for example, trying to have a list of _any_ monoids and convert it to list of _any_ semigroups (which I can duplicate, etc.) `C (Ctx Monoid) Semigroup` means that I can 'cast' Monoid to Semigroup

Comment: You never need `IncoherentInstances`. Convert one of your instances to bare `C p a b` with a constraint (say) `a ~ Ctx a’ =>`